# Using transition to open a simple drop down I have basics but can't fit it with my design

Tags: html, css, transition

I need to save some real estate on a page I'm working on so I wanted to simply be able to hover over the topics and have the sub-topics then accessible from a "drop-down" (actually a div that eases out) div.

Here is a fiddle for the effect I want:

https://jsfiddle.net/170z6pj1/

However I can't seem to get my brain around how to make it work with this, whereby I want the text "How to..." to be the trigger to cause the ease-out:

https://jsfiddle.net/170z6pj1/3/

I've tried various ways to try and get the id="menu" onto the "How to..." or "titleB" divs but they never work if I do it that way. I realise my base CSS isn't correct for that to work, but I just can't wrap my head around what I need to change - first time trying transitions.

Thanks for any and all responses.

p.s. As far as I know I have to use the "max-height workaround" to get it to dynamically adjust to the correct length of the list items.

```
HTML: 

<div id="titleA">
  <div id="titleB"></div>How to...</div>
<div id="menu">
  <a>Hover to expand</a>
  <ul id="list">
    <li>How to book a meeting room</li>
    <li>How to book catering</li>
    <li>How to report extra cleaning requirement</li>
    <li>How to report a fault</li>
    <li>How to report a H&amp;S issue</li>
    <li>How to book a hot desk</li>
    <li>What happens if I get locked in</li>
    <li>How to request consumables - for kitchens, photocopiers, etc.</li>
    <li>Out of hours issues affecting buildings / How to make contact in an emergency</li>
    <li>Recycling guide</li>
    <li>Complaints and feedback</li>
  </ul>
</div>

CSS: 

#menu #list {
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 1.5s ease-out;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 99%;
  border: 1px solid #c8ced0;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#menu:hover #list {
  max-height: 500px;
  transition: max-height 1.5s ease-in;
}

#titleA {
  position: relative;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #5bc0de;
  padding-top: 14px;
  padding-left: 22px;
  height: 54px;
  width: calc(100% - 35px);
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 19px;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-weight: bold;


}

#titleB {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: -20px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  background: #5bc0de;
  transform: skew(30deg);
}
```

After some playing around, I've got a step closer to the design I want by cutting out "non-essentials". Still looking for a solution to keep my original design (second fiddle) though!

https://jsfiddle.net/170z6pj1/4/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's because you apply padding and border to : ul id="list"

Comment: That has nothing to do with this design issue as far as I can tell. I just don't see how to apply the on-hover effect to where I want.